# Verify I have not broken a public class API

Tags: .net, mono, clr, command-line-interface

Does somebody know of a good way of verifying that the current code-base doesn't change existing public APIs? I would like to run this as a part of a continuous integration process.

Something like the set:

(the union of all current public method signatures and public type names) intersection with (all previous public method signatures and public type names)

- should equal (deep compare) all previous public method signatures and public type names

Perhaps some project has used Mono.Cecil or NDepend and is capable of analysing this from the command line?

Comment: ...when all you have is a hammer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a blog post a while ago about [how to avoid API breaking change](http://codebetter.com/patricksmacchia/2008/01/20/avoid-api-breaking-changes/) with NDepend and its code query and rule capabilities. *Disclaimer: I am one of the developers of the tool*

Since then, NDepend has evolved and its query language as well. If you download NDepend trial and analysis the two versions of your code base where you'd like to search for API breaking change, have a look in the default code rules group **API Breaking Changes** for the following [CQLinq rules](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#CQL).

- [API Breaking Changes: Types](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_API_Breaking_Changes__Types.html)
- [API Breaking Changes: Methods](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_API_Breaking_Changes__Methods.html)
- [API Breaking Changes: Fields](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_API_Breaking_Changes__Fields.html)
- [API Breaking Changes: Interfaces and Abstract Classes](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_API_Breaking_Changes__Interfaces_and_Abstract_Classes.html)

Executing this rule looks like for example (diff between NUnit v2.5.8 and v2.5.3):

[image: API breaking changes]

You'll find also these default code rules and queries relevant:

- [Broken serializable types](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Broken_serializable_types.html)
- [API: New publicly visible types](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_API__New_publicly_visible_types.html)
- [API: New publicly visible methods](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_API__New_publicly_visible_methods.html)
- [API: New publicly visible fields](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_API__New_publicly_visible_fields.html)

Comment: Nice indeed. Gonna check the blog post out.

Answer (score 1):

There's corcompare, a tool that Mono uses internally to [compare their API](http://www.mono-project.com/Generating_class_status_pages) to the Microsoft .Net implementation. If you'd like to generate a HTML report like Mono does, [corcompare is available on github](https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mcs/tools/corcompare) (buildable with Visual Studio). There's also a nice GUI frontend called [gui-compare](https://github.com/mono/mono-tools/tree/master/gui-compare) that uses the same Cecil backend (UI requires gtk-sharp installed). I've used it before and it was very comfortable - just point it at two different dll's and a nice comparison window pops out. Corcompare, on the other hand, generates XML API descriptors, should you want to automate this check.

Those tools validate method descriptors (including parameter names, as you can bind parameters by name in C# 4), visibility and attributes (on assembly, class, method and parameter level).